# NAV Bar not appearing after embedding VC in NavagationVC

Tags: xcode, navigation

Attempting to follow some noob tutorials and I have exhausted google search but I cannot seem to figure out why my Nav Bar is not showing when I embed my VC in a Navigation Controller. I am using Xcode 14.2 with iPhone 14 pro max as my phone in storyboard. Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Tried clicking off "translucent" and it turns the whole top of the Navigation bar completely black

Answer (score 0):

what does it mean 'not showing'? In Xcode or in Simulator when you run the app? What would you like to see?

here is my screenshot with app running
[Xcode with Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVfVI.png)

Comment: I am thinking this is a UI update with Xcode it used to show a nav bar with an offset color and line making it now its a navigation bar